# Content region & block not being rendered in drupal 8

Tags: drupal

I created region for sidebar and  render it but it wont show up any pages

i'm not sure where this issue belongs, but this seemed a good place to start.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very good question since you did not provide any details on how exactly you created the region (should be defined in your theme_name.info.yml) or how you are trying to render it in your template (should be something along the lines of {{ page.region_name }}).

Since you have not provided example markup, I will assume that you did everything correctly and the region still does not show up anywhere (for example, when showing the region render preview or when trying to assign blocks to regions).

In that case, try clearing the cache (go to /admin/config/development/performance and click "Clear all caches"), then see if the region shows up. If it does not, try and activate a different theme, then reactivate your theme again.

If after performing these actions your region still, does not show up, see above: Please provide example code.